# xPath strange behaviour - selecting ALL elements even if [1] set

Tags: xpath

today I stumbled upon a very interesting case (at least for me). I am messing around with Selenium and xPath and tried to get some elements, but got a strange behaviour:

```
<div class="resultcontainer">
   <div class="info">
     <div class="title">
        <a>
           some text
        </a>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="resultcontainer">
   <div class="info">
     <div class="title">
        <a>
           some other text
        </a>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="resultcontainer">
   <div class="info">
     <div class="title">
        <a>
           some even unrelated text
        </a>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is my data. 
When i run the following xPath query:

```
//div[@class="title"][1]/a
```

I get as a result **ALL**  instead of only the first one. But if I query:

```
//div[@class="resultcontainer"][1]/div[@class="info"]/div[@class="title"]/a
```

I get only the first , not all.

Is there some divine reason behind that?

Best regards,
bisko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
(//div[@class="title"])[1]/a
```

This:

```
//div[@class="title"][1]/a
```

selects all (`<a>` elements that are children of) `<div>` elements that have a `@class` of `'title'`, that are the first children of their parents (in this context). Which means: it selects *all* of them.

The working XPath selects all `<div>` elements that have a `@class` of `'title'` - and of those it takes the first one.

The predicates (the expressions in square brackets `[]`) are applied to each element that matched the preceding location step (i.e. `"//div"`) *individually*. To apply a predicate to a filtered set of nodes, you need to make the grouping clear with parentheses.

Consequently, this:

```
//div[1][@class="title"]/a
```

would select all `<div>` elements, take the first one, and then filter it down futher by checking the `@class` value. Also not what you want. ;-)